# Is there an example of Salesforce Bulk Api?

Tags: bulk-api, c#

I am trying to shift my current code base to start using the Rest service provided by Salesforce instead of Soap particularly  the Bulk Api feature.
Is there a c# example that shows how for example i can perform crud on hundreds of Salesforce entities using the Bulk Api ?

Comment: Are you aiming to modify hundreds of _entities_ (different objects), or _records_ (of one or more objects)? The Bulk API is oriented at updating hundreds of thousands or millions of records per object in one job. If your volume is much lower, you should probably be using the REST API.

Comment: Thanks for the update . I need to create over 500K records , i assume i can use the Bulk Api for that ?   Is each batch job per object only ?  Is there any example of doing this using C#.